# Stationary point of matrix function vs eigen decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, matrix-calculus

Given a scalar objective function,

$\mathrm{argmin}_P$ $f\left(P\right) = ||P^TAP||^2_F+\mathrm{tr}\left(P^TBP\right)$

where $P$ is an unknown matrix, A and B are known.

A stationary point $P$ of $f\left(P\right)$ should be a matrix of $d$ smallest eigenvectors of $M\left(P\right)$, where

$M\left(P\right)=APP^TA+\frac{1}{2}B$

How to prove the above statement? What is the relation between the stationary point and the eigenvectors?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the gradient
$$\eqalign{
f &= P^TAP:P^TAP + B:PP^T \\
df
 &= 2P^TAP:(P^TA\,dP+dP^TAP) + B:(P\,dP^T+dP\,P^T) \\
 &= (2A^TPP^TAP + 2APP^TA^TP +BP+B^TP):dP \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial P}
 &= 2A^TPP^TAP + 2APP^TA^TP +BP+B^TP \\
}$$
If $A$ and $B$ are symmetric then this can be simplified to
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial P} &= 4MP \\
}$$
Set the gradient to zero and solve
$$\eqalign{
MP &= 0 \\
}$$
Obviously, $P=0$ is the global minimum. Other stationary points might be characterized as follows:

---

Assume $P={\tt[}\,p_1\;p_2\;\ldots\,{\tt]}\;$ then the columns of $P$ satisfy
$\,Mp_k = 0.\;$

So the $p_k$ are eigenvectors of $M$ associated with the eigenvalue $\lambda = 0.$

---

**NB:** In several steps above, a colon is used to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB) = {\rm Tr}(B^TA) = B:A \\
}$$

Comment: Wow! Elegant and clear derivation! Thank you