# Calculate $\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{A}}\lVert \mathbf{A}^{\top}\mathbf{AX}-\mathbf{X} \rVert _{F}^{2}$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, matrix-norms, scalar-fields

> Calculate $\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{A}}\lVert \mathbf{A}^{\top}\mathbf{AX}-\mathbf{X} \rVert _{F}^{2}$ with $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{M\times N}$ and $\mathbf{X}\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times D}$, and find $\mathbf{A}$ satisfying $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{A}}\lVert \mathbf{A}^{\top}\mathbf{AX}-\mathbf{X} \rVert _{F}^{2}=\mathbf{0}_{M\times N}$$

---

**My Efforts**

I know that $\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{B}}\lVert \mathbf{B} \rVert _{F}^{2}=2\mathbf{B}$, and am not sure that if $\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{A}}(\mathbf{A}^\top\mathbf{A})=2\mathbf{A}$ (I get these from [The Matrix Cookbook](http://matrixcookbook.com)). How to get the final derivative, and solve $\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{A}}\lVert \mathbf{A}^{\top}\mathbf{AX}-\mathbf{X} \rVert _{F}^{2}=\mathbf{0}_{M\times N}$?

Comment: The norm should be quartic in $\bf A$. Hence, the gradient should be cubic.

Comment: I advise you to use the notations and the techniques you will find in the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3868172/305862).

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2112621/339790).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripping away the norm, you're attempting a least-squares solution of
$$A^TAX = X \quad\implies\quad A^TA = XX^+$$
QR decomposition yields
$$\eqalign{
QR &= XX^+ \\
(QR)^TQR &= (XX^+)^T(XX^+) \\
R^TQ^TQR &= (XX^+)(XX^+) \\
R^TR &= (XX^+) \\
}$$
Therefore $A=R$ is one possible solution. To obtain the desired dimensions, drop the last $(M-N)$ rows of $R$.

Since there was no requirement for $A$ to be triangular, other (non-triangular) solutions are possible using different factorizations, e.g. SVD or EVD decompositions.

Comment: Hi @greg, thank you very much for your help! What can I do if I hope that $\mathbf{A}=\alpha\mathbf{B}$ with $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and each element of $\mathbf{B}$ can only be in $\{-1,+1\}$ or $\{0,1\}$ (i.e., I want to get bipolar and binary optimal matrices)? I was trying to calculate the derivative first and then adding a regularization term in the original optimization problem. (Please see my another posted problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4431816/find-mathbfa-minimizing-lvert-mathbfa-top-mathbfax-mathbfx-rv.)